# A cipher for people who don't normally enjoy ciphers

Tags: cipher

I've never been a fan of ciphers/encryption. Truth be told, despite my love of puzzles (and the amount of time I spend here on Puzzling.SE), I'm just no good at them and haven't properly learnt the strategies for trying to crack them.

So in an effort to expand on the types of ciphers and hopefully broaden the audience, I offer you the following challenge:

> I have encrypted a five-word phrase in the form 
>   _ _ _ _/ _ _ _ _, / _ _ _/ _ _ _ _ _ _/ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
>   [word lengths are (4) (4), (3) (6) (6)]
>
> However, instead of just encrypting it once, I have done so six times, using six different methods.
>
> The output for each encryption is as follows:
>   [image: Encryption Output]

The final answer has two parts to it. First, the completed five-word phrase (which I suspect will be discovered first) and second, the six different encryption methods, all of which must be detailed in the answer.

*The decrypted phrase will tell you to do something, so make sure you do it :) You wouldn't want to make the puzzle sad, would you?*

Some excellent community effort so far! The phrase and methods 2, 4 and 5 have been cracked, so I'll throw some subtle hints for the remaining three methods in

Method 3

> How **often** do you see a 3-letter word have a higher value than a 4-letter word?

Method 6

> The order of the letters doesn't seem logical in isolation, but if it ever got changed, many of us would struggle to adapt!

Comment: Shouldn't the phrase have 4 words?

Comment: I have an idea for Method 4, but only if word 1 is 35 instead of 45. thanks!

Comment: I'll need to double check in the morning

Comment: Sorry I was wrong

Comment: "Hash" might be a better word than "cipher" or "encryption", since you can't easily go back from the value to the word.

Comment: @Harfatum yeah that's true, but I guess the technical definition doesn't detract from the enjoyment of the puzzle? I suppose if I hadn't made each value the sum of all the letter values then it would have been more "cipher-like" (but it also would have been substantially easier)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is a summary of all answers provided by everyone, I have credited them, if I left anyone out, please state it in the comments. Thanks!**

**Complete** Answer:

The phrase is:

> WELL DONE, NOW UPVOTE PUZZLE (which I did), thanks to @DrXorile (approved by OP in comment)

Method 1 is

> Sum of **Scrabble** values of each letter. So much thanks to @Braegh! (approved by OP in comment) 
>  My original guess: 
> Ceasar shifting, the number being the rotation number, as all numbers are not larger than 26. 26 means the word is not shifted at all. (I believe that this is wrong...)

Method 2 is:

> Sum of values in **A1Z26** scheme, Thanks to @ImongMama (approved by OP in comment)

Method 3 is:

> The sum of values of each letter according to the **frequency** (descending): etaoi nshrd lcumw fgypb vkjxq z, where e=1, z=26, 
>  "WELL"=15+1+11+11=38 
>  THANKS TO @NudgeNudge!!

Method 4 is:

> the sum of values of each letter on a **telephone keypad**, like this:
> [image: keypad]
>  e.g. for "DONE" 3+(6+6+6)+(6+6)+(3+3)=39 (approved by OP in comment)

Method 5 is

> the sum of **ASCII** values of each letter, since they add up to around 80-90 per letter. (approved by OP in comment)

And method 6:

> is the **sum** of the values for each letter according to its position on a QWERTY keyboard, like this:
> [image: qwerty encryption]

PS:

> I really enjoyed this puzzle. Thanks so much, @Dmihawk!

Comment: Good spotting! :)

Comment: Method 2 and 6 are correct (I didn't know method 2 had an actual name - so that was cool to learn). For method 1, perhaps consider why one 6-letter word is "worth" more than the other...

Comment: Method 6? @Dmihawk Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, meant 5!

Comment: You are absolutely correct on method 4, but I'm not sure how you got to 35 for the first word. I get 9 + 6 + 15 + 15 = 45

Comment: so sorry, my fault. I calculated it wrongly...

Comment: For method 3, I believe rot13(gur ahzrevpny inyhr bs gur yrggre vf rdhny gb vgf cbfvgvba ba gur yvfg bs yrggref beqrerq ol eryngvir serdhrapl va Ratyvfu (r svefg, gura  g, n, b, v...))

Comment: I'm really glad you enjoyed it @OmegaKrypton :)

Answer (score 7):

Method 2 is

> Sum of A1Z26 values

Answer (score 7):

I believe Method 1 is

> the (English) Scrabble value for each word.

Comment: Well done! Good find :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Omega Krypton's method 5, the phrase is:

> WELL DONE, NOW UPVOTE PUZZLE

I figured this out by going through all the english words that would fit those sums. The last word stood out, and I got the remaining ones except for the fourth quite quickly. The fourth wasn't in my dictionary, but easy enough to guess and check...

Comment: Nicely done :) now you just need to deduce the other 5 encryption methods!

Comment: I upvoted the puzzle lah :)